# How to Mass Delete All Inactive Flows in an Org

Tags: soql, visual-workflow

I am trying to do some org cleanup and delete all inactive flows. These flows are not being referenced by other components (layouts, other flows, etc.).

Currently, I am using this query to gather all inactive flows:

```
SELECT TriggerType, ProcessType, IsActive, ApiName, Label, LastModifiedDate FROM FlowDefinitionView WHERE IsActive=false AND TriggerType IN ('PlatformEvent', 'RecordAfterSave', 'RecordBeforeSave', 'Scheduled')
```

But when I go and run a Delete in the Anonymous Apex, it says DML does not support deletion.

Is there no way to mass delete inactive flows using a query, apex, etc.? Are we stuck creating a list view and deleting them one by one in the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't currently a way to mass delete flows.

See the idea on the idea exchange:  https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiO8UAJ/allow-mass-deletion-of-inactive-process-builder-versions

UnofficialSF have solutions if you're willing to go through the process.

See also

- https://unofficialsf.com/flow-and-process-builder-list-view-with-batch-delete/
- https://unofficialsf.com/flow-and-process-builder-list-view-with-batch-delete-v2/

Answer (score 0):

There's actuallly a way to first mass-deactivate and then delete flows in [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/)
It's a bit cumbersome as you first need to deactivate flows by:

1. Unchecking the *activeVersionNumberSpecified* flag for them
2. Clicking on Update All or Update Selected

Then you'll need to delete the rows with flows you want to remove from the spreadsheet and click on Update All.
[image]